jakarta.persistence.EntityExistsException when trying to delete object via Hibernate
I am using Hibernate 6 as my ORM with PostgesSQL 15 as the underlying DB.
We recently have upgraded from Hibernate 3 and have been sorting out the changes needed as part of the upgrade.
I am trying to find out why I get the following error when I call
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().remove(myObject);
I tried rewriting the deletion as a HQL query as follows and that executes without any issue.
MutationQuery deletionQuery = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createMutationQuery("delete from " + type+ " where id = :id");
        deletionQuery.setParameter("id", id);
        int n = deletionQuery.executeUpdate();

With the first version I added logging to look at the Object Hash Ids and I don't see any other objects being handed out by Hibernate:
[INFO] [UserDAOImpl] USERDAO_RA, id :RichardFeynman refID:com.mycompany.model.User@3a497f7b
[INFO] [UserDAOImpl] USERDAO_RA, id :RichardFeynman refID:com.mycompany.model.User@3a497f7b
[INFO] [UserDAOImpl] USERDAO_RA, id :RichardFeynman refID:com.mycompany.model.User@3a497f7b
[INFO] [UserDAOImpl] USERDAO_RA, id :RichardFeynman refID:com.mycompany.model.User@3a497f7b
[INFO] [UserDAOImpl] USERDAO_RA, id :RichardFeynman refID:com.mycompany.model.User@3a497f7b
[INFO] [UserDAOImpl] USERDAO_R, id :RichardFeynman refID:com.mycompany.model.User@3a497f7b

Error:
jakarta.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.mycompany.model.User#randall]
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:182) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireDelete(SessionImpl.java:953) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:874) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.remove(SessionImpl.java:2285) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at com.mycompany.dao.hibernate.CommonDAOImpl.delete(CommonDAOImpl.java:161) ~[mycompany-services-impl.jar:?]

